# How to remove li element from li

Tags: jquery, html

i have mulitple li like this..

What i want is when the li is clicked i dont want to fire click event of ".actiontools" class which is under all li

```
<li>
 <div class="bordered collapse-tree">
    <div class="actionTools">
        <div class="navItemcustom">
            <a href="#" class="actionToolsDropDown"><span class="">
                Actions</span></a>
            <div class="dropscustom">
                <a >Add</a>
                <a >edit</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        test

    </div>
</div>

<ol>

    <li id="menuid">
        <div class="bordered  ">
            <div class="actionTools">
                <div class="navItemcustom">
                    <a href="#" class="actionToolsDropDown"><span class="">
                        Actions</span></a>
                    <div class="dropscustom">
                        <a >Add</a>
                        <a >edit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                new

            </div>
        </div>

    </li>
</ol>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function (cash) {
    $.fn.collapsibleList = function () {
        this.find("li").each(function (i, li) {

        });

        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
$(".collapsibleList").collapsibleList();

</script>
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/napper7/BTcwr/

Comment: i want something like when anchor tag is clicked in ".actiontools" class i want the default behaviour of li(collapsible) to stop and fire the anchor tag event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("li").find(".actionTools").click(function() {
    return false;
});​
```

Comment: i want something like when anchor tag is clicked in ".actiontools" class i want the default behaviour of li(collapsible) to stop and fire the anchor tag event

Comment: nothing got it working instead of using return false i used e.StopPropogation

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li").click(function(event)}{
    event.preventDefault();
    //do your stufff


});
```

Comment: i want something like when anchor tag is clicked in ".actiontools" class i want the default behaviour of li(collapsible) to stop and fire the anchor tag event.